# Ubuntu & Virtual Box - Follow Up Question

Tags: virtualization

Have downloaded Ubuntu Server 14.04, 64-bit.  Have also downloaded Virtual Box 4.3.10 (which supports 64 bits).  My operating system is Windows 7 - 64 bit.

When I configure Virtual Box for Ubuntu, and name the new file "linux ubuntu," the system type changes to "Linux" and the version changes to "Ubuntu 32."  There isn't an option for "Ubuntu 64," which seems to cause a problem later when I try to run Ubuntu within the Virtual Box.

What is happening?  I'm on a 64-bit system, I've downloaded a version of Ubuntu that's for 64-bits only, my version of Virtual Box is the newest, and allows for 64-bit systems.  Why am I not seeing an option for "Ubuntu 64-bit" when I try to create an Ubuntu file within Virtual Box?  How do I fix this problem?

Comment: *"and name the new file "linux ubuntu,""*, why? *" There isn't an option for "Ubuntu 64,"*" it doesn't? It should have? *"which seems to cause a problem later"* what kind of problem?

Comment: You may need to enable vitrualization technology in your bios

Comment: @Braiam: VirtualBox does differentiate between the 32-bit version and the 64-bit version during OS selection.

Comment: Bodhi commented that "You may need to enable virtualization in BIOS."  I just enabled it, and Virtual Box now gives me the "Ubuntu(64)" bit option, rather than just the 32-bit option.